How to connect elasticsearch with ranger (while creating service) when xpack.security is enabled?
When xpack.security.enabled is set to true in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml, I am able to create users in elasticsearch or kibana UI but ranger gives connection failed for elasticsearch when creating service using ranger UI. Whereas xpack.security.enabled set to false will connect the ranger with elasticsearch but I am not getting the login page in kibana. Neither I am able to create users.
Is there a possible way so that I could create elasticsearch service in ranger and also be able to create users in Kibana?
